# Why is my xsd:choice between elements of different types failing?

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I'm trying to validate an XML with XSD, but I can't understand what is wrong with my XSD.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Grades xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="grade.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Grade description="Pass">
        <LetterGrade>A+</LetterGrade>
        <GradePoint>4.00</GradePoint>
        <Percentage>80% and above</Percentage>
    </Grade>
    <Grade description="Pass">
        <LetterGrade>A</LetterGrade>
        <GradePoint>4.00</GradePoint>
        <Percentage>70% to 80%</Percentage>
    </Grade>
    <Grade description="Pass">
        <LetterGrade>B</LetterGrade>
        <GradePoint>3.00</GradePoint>
        <Percentage>60% to 70%</Percentage>
    </Grade>
    <Grade description="Pass">
        <LetterGrade>C</LetterGrade>
        <GradePoint>2.00</GradePoint>
        <Percentage>50% to 60%</Percentage>
    </Grade>
    <Grade description="Pass">
        <LetterGrade>D</LetterGrade>
        <GradePoint>1.00</GradePoint>
        <Percentage>40% to 50%</Percentage>
    </Grade>
    <Grade description="Fail">
        <LetterGrade>F</LetterGrade>
        <GradePoint>0</GradePoint>
        <Percentage>Below 40%</Percentage>
    </Grade>
    <Grade description="Incomplete"> Incomplete module/project/independent study due
    to medical/financial/other reasons (may be in 1 or both components of the module).
        <LetterGrade>N</LetterGrade>
    </Grade>
</Grades>
```

**XSD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:complexType name="gradeDetails">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="LetterGrade" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="GradePoint" type="xs:decimal"/>
        <xs:element name="Percentage" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="description" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="gradeNode">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="LetterGrade" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="description" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="Grades">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="Grade" type="gradeDetails" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="Grade" type="gradeNode" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

I tried validating it with the online validator xmlvalidation.com and I'm getting these errors:

> Errors in the XML document: 
>       
> 36:    10  cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'Grade' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.
>       
> 36:    10  cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'Grade' is not complete. One of '{"":GradePoint}' is expected.

Somewhat, I understood these error messages. I know it's because there are elements missing in the last `<Grade>` tag. And to solve it I created 2 global types and used choice. What is wrong with it now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XSD as written isn't valid on its own because the `Grade` elements (as children of `Grades`) cannot have two different types as you're trying to do.  You should have received an error message about this along the lines of the following:

> **cos-element-consistent**: Error for type '#AnonType_Grades'. Multiple
>   elements with name 'Grade', with different types, appear in the model
>   group.

and

> **cos-nonambig**: Grade and Grade (or elements from their substitution
>   group) violate "Unique Particle Attribution". During validation
>   against this schema, ambiguity would be created for those two
>   particles.

The simplified XSD shown below eliminates those errors and successfully validates against your unchanged XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:complexType name="GradeType" mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="LetterGrade" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="GradePoint" minOccurs="0" type="xs:decimal"/>
      <xs:element name="Percentage" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="description" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="Grades">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Grade" type="GradeType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Very efficient use of the minOccurs. Didn't think of this. Thanks.